# Make the Facebook like button comment popup anchored on right with box count layout

Tags: facebook, button, popup, alignment, comments

I'm trying to properly align the Facebook like button's comment popup. I'm using box count layout so that I can align all the Facebook/Twitter/Google+/Whatever buttons on the right side.

Here is my actual page layout. It looks like I want.
[image: My actual buttons layout, it looks fine]

But once I click the Like button, the comment popup appears anchored from the left and is out of the window. Bummer.
[image: Crappy result]

What I want is simply have the popup anchored from the right instead of the left
[image: Google's +1 button does it properly, so why not Facebook?]
I tried all versions of the button. IFRAME version does not show the comment box but can't be properly aligned. HTML5 and XFBML are properly aligned but they both show the popup out of the window.

I don't see any parameter in [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) to adjust the alignment of the comment popup or to force the comment popup to be opened in a real browser popup. BTW, this can't be adjusted by CSS since the damn popup is inside a damn IFRAME, even when I'm using HTML5 and XFBML markup.

Is there a clean way to:

1. Anchor this popup to the right
2. Open the popup in an actual browser popup (window.open())
3. Hide the popup

Is there a way to achieve that? Google +1 button does the job perfectly without needing to add a lot of code.

Of course, the easy solution would be to move my buttons on the left side but it sucks.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, Nicolas! Did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The Facebook widget is an iframe so we have no control over it. What I did is put the widget in a container with overflow:hidden so the popup doesn't show up but it's quite dirty : http://twittercats.com/

Comment: Maybe you can make it stick to left and move to right once it is clicked. (sounds hard, but why not try..).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<center>
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FID_HERE&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;width=50&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:30px;" allowtransparency="false"></iframe>
```

Replace ID_HERE with your page id